# How do I evade the limit of 100 entries in python splunk query

Tags: python, splunk

When executing a query via the splunk SDK, apparently the results are clipped after 100 entries. How to get around this limit?

I tried:

```
>job = service.jobs.create(qstring,max_count=0, max_time=0, count=10000)
>while not job.is_ready():
    time.sleep(1)
>out = list(results.ResultsReader(job.results()))
>print(len(out))
100
```

but the same query in the splunk web interface produces over 100 lines of results.

Comment: http://dev.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAADQT suggests that the http request should contain a "count" line in its data.

Comment: what is `qstring` here? Is the query limiting the results to 100 items?

Comment: No it certainly isn't :) that's why the same very search in the webapp returns more than 100 entries. qstring is specific to my search, and I can't connect you to my data sources, of course.

Comment: What is `job["resultCount"]` when the job is ready?

Comment: job["resultCount"]->'1051'

Comment: That's a funny tag there. I actually misread it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack which appears to work (but this is surely not the right way to do this):

in splunklib.binding

HttpLib.get and HttpLib.post, add the following line to the beginning of each method:

```
kwargs['count'] = 100000
```

Answer (score 4):

Try job.results(**count=0**)
count=0 means no limit.

Comment: it *does" work on my side. 
code: for result in results.ResultsReader(job.results(count=0)):

Comment: In my case (with a saved search) it did work if I passed count = 0 in as one of the kwargs to job.results.