# Splunk query returns fewer results than expected

Tags: python-2.7, splunk, splunk-query

I am using this command to get top 200 results from Splunk on my_field:

```
q = "search index=idx host=nets* mydomain.com | top limit=200 my_field"
```

When I run this in Splunk, it gives me 200 results.
However, when I run it using the Splunk Python SDK, I get only 100 results.

```
service = client.connect(host=HOST, username=USER, password=PASS)

extra_args = {"earliest_time": "-1h",
                  "latest_time": "now"}

q = "search index=idx host=nets* mydomain.com | top limit=200 my_field"
res = service.jobs.oneshot(q, **extra_args)

reader = results.ResultsReader(res)
top_jobs = []

for row in reader:
  top_jobs.append(row['my_field'])

print len(top_jobs) # always returns 100, or any number less than 100 that is specified in the query.
```

Is there any other way to specify the number of results?

Comment: Try suggestions posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492425/how-do-i-evade-the-limit-of-100-entries-in-python-splunk-query

Comment: Your Python query looks like it's only searching for the past hour. Do you know the time frame for the query run directly through Splunk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I evade the limit of 100 entries in python splunk query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492425/how-do-i-evade-the-limit-of-100-entries-in-python-splunk-query)